# RxJava2: Problems with retryWhen()

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm trying to implement a `retryWhen` operation for my `Completable` chain using this [blog post as a basis](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/), but I keep getting errors. I'm trying to check whether the error was a `HttpException` and if so, refresh the token and try again. The chain looks something like this:

```
Completable c = ...;

c = c.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
    if (error instanceof HttpExcetion) {
        return authHandler.refreshToken().flatMap(token -> Completable.complete());
    }
    return Completable.error(error);
}));
```

However, this won't compile, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Since I'm using RxJava 2 I shouldn't emit `null` like they do on the article, but that wouldn't seem to fix the issue anyway. I even tried a more simple version, basically copied straight from that article and replaced `Observable` with `Completable`:

```
c.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
        return Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }));
```

This won't compile either. The error is this:

```
Error:(31, 51) error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
(argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
Completable cannot be converted to Publisher<? extends R>)
where R,T are type-variables:
R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends R>>)
T extends Object declared in class Flowable
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: First, `Observable` and `Completable` are on completely different type hieararchies and are not 1:1 interchangeable; thus you need `toFlowable()` to convert to the receiving type. Second, `Completable`s don't emit values and thus you can't use it directly to singal retry (like with the `Completable.timer()` example) nor can you use them to signal completion in a flatMap scenario. More generally, flatMapping an empty source doesn't terminate the end stream unlike flatMapping an error source.